# pgfornament alignment not perfect and psutils incompatible

Tags: pgfornament

When compiling

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}                           % No page numbers
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[object=pgfhan]{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
                        
% corners
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east)
            {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=v]{4}};
        \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west)
            {\pgfornament[width=5cm]{4}};
        \node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east)
            {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=c]{4}};
        \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west)
            {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=h]{4}};

% borders
        \node[anchor=north,xscale=2.2] at (current page.north)
            {\pgfornament[height=2.5mm]{30}};
        \node[anchor=south,xscale=2.2] at (current page.south)
            {\pgfornament[height=2.5mm,symmetry=c]{30}};    
        \node[anchor=east,shift={(-2.5mm,-10.5cm)},yscale=4,rotate=-90] 
            at (current page.east)
            {\pgfornament[height=2.5mm]{30}};       
        \node[anchor=west,shift={(2.5mm,-10.5cm)},yscale=4,rotate=90] 
            at (current page.west)
            {\pgfornament[height=2.5mm]{30}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with `xelatex` version `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)`, I have the following problems:

- the vertical borders are not perfectly aligned
- I can't use psutils release 1 patchlevel 17 prior to use pdftops

`gs` can read the PDF file correctly, but not `pstops` nor `psresize`.
The PDF file prints, but cropped (expected behavior).

Using `pdf2ps` helps. It makes the file compatible with `pstops`, but I have to specify the paper size to avoid cropping the top border:

```
pdf2ps -paper=A4 frame-2.pdf frame-2.ps
```

Using `pstops "@0.8(21mm,29.7mm)" -pA4 frame-2.ps frame-2ss.ps` produces a file that

- prints as desired on A4 paper.
- is not shown properly centered by `gs`.

Is my `AVlinux` system `Linux 6.0.0-10.1-liquorix-amd64 #1 ZEN SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC liquorix 6.0-6~mx21+1 (2022-11-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux` not set to default A4 paper size?

Comment: `sudo paperconfig -p a4` sets the default paper size to A4. That fixes the alignment issue when viewing with `gs` (I did not specify paper size for gs). I also changed the default locale. Thanks MX tools.

Comment: I don't get proper alignment with your code at all. The corners are fine, but the borders aren't.

Answer (score 0):

You can align them correctly with pdfTeX, XeTeX or LuaTeX using the `pgfornament` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}                           % No page numbers
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[object=pgfhan]{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
  
  % corners
  \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=v]{4}};
  \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west) {\pgfornament[width=5cm]{4}};
  \node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east) {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=c]{4}};
  \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=h]{4}};
  
  % borders
  \node[anchor=north,xscale=2.2] at (current page.north) {\pgfornament[height=2.5mm]{30}};
  \node[anchor=south,xscale=2.2] at (current page.south) {\pgfornament[height=2.5mm,symmetry=c]{30}};    
  \node[anchor=south,yscale=4,rotate around={-90:(current page.west)}] at (current page.west) {\pgfornament[height=2.5mm]{30}};
  \node[anchor=south,yscale=4,rotate around={90:(current page.east)}] at (current page.east) {\pgfornament[height=2.5mm]{30}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned borders]